# Logout on browser or tab close

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I need to log out a user in case he closes the browser/tab running my website. I have set the `isPersistant` bool to `false`, yet it does not log the user out. I want force the user to log in again if the tab is closed. I don't want to use jQuery.

Here is some of the relevant snippets from my current code:

**AccountController**

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username,
    model.Password, false, shouldLockout: true);`
```

**Startup.Auth**

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
        // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))                      
     }
});            

app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
```

Comment: It can't be achieved that easily. You need something like a heartbeat to tell the server that the user still has a tab/window open. That is, regularly send a confirmation from the browser to the server (trough a HTTP request). Consider this: what happens when a user has two tabs open and they both contain you application and the user closes one of them?

Comment: @AndreiV I see what you are geting at. I'm currently investigating SignalR as a possible solution, the only problem I see is that a postback will break the connection to the Hub, which might look like a tab being closed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by postback and breaking the connection. What I was thinking of was a JS script, which periodically (1-2-3-X minutes) sends an AJAX request to the server, informing it that the user still has at least one tab open.

Comment: That is in a nutshell what SignalR does, but it has a constant connection. When the site performs a postback, that connection will be lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @AndreiV state, there is no way of detecting when the user closes the browser.

I opted to implement SignalR and monitor the connection for a disconnect event, at which point, based on some criteria, I un-authenticate the user's session. If he then comes back the the site, I know that his session is no longer valid and he is redirected to the login page.